# How to link a SQLite c file (the Amalgamation) with cpp application?

Tags: c++, c, sqlite, embedded-linux, static-linking

I want to build this process on an embedded Linux without installing sqlite3 or sqlite3-dev (I already tried to install them and it worked out).

I've 4 files in the directory : main.cpp sqlite3.c sqlite3.h example.db

I included the sqlite3.h in the main.cpp this way:

```
extern "C"{
#include "sqlite3.h"
}
```

Then I typed those commands :

```
gcc -c sqlite3.c -o sqlite3.o
g++ -c main.cpp -o main.o
```

and it was already so far, then I wrote this

```
g++ -o main.out main.o -L.
```

but I'm getting those errors

```
main.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0xf6): undefined reference to `sqlite3_open'
main.cpp:(.text+0x16d): undefined reference to `sqlite3_exec'
main.cpp:(.text+0x1c6): undefined reference to `sqlite3_exec'
main.cpp:(.text+0x1f7): undefined reference to `sqlite3_free'
main.cpp:(.text+0x25c): undefined reference to `sqlite3_exec'
main.cpp:(.text+0x299): undefined reference to `sqlite3_exec'
main.cpp:(.text+0x2ca): undefined reference to `sqlite3_free'
main.cpp:(.text+0x32f): undefined reference to `sqlite3_exec'
main.cpp:(.text+0x33b): undefined reference to `sqlite3_close'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How to statically link those files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually linking with the SQLite object file `sqlite3.o`.

The linker doesn't know about files or libraries that aren't specified explicitly, so you need to do e.g.

```
g++ -o main.out main.o sqlite3.o
```

---

Considering the other error you get, you need to build with the `-pthread` option, both when compiling *and* when linking.

And the `-L` option is to add a path that the library searches for libraries you name with the `-l` (lower-case L) option. The linker will *not* automatically search for any libraries or object files. You really need to specify them explicitly when linking.

To summarize, build like this:

```
g++ -Wall -pthread main.cpp -c
gcc -Wall -pthread sqlite3.c -c
g++ -pthread -o main.out main.o sqlite3.o -ldl
```

Note that we now also link with the `dl` library, as specified in the documentation linked to by Shawn.

Comment: I tried it and I got this: 
lib_sqlite3.o: In function `pthreadMutexAlloc':
lib_sqlite3.c:(.text+0x4137): undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_init'
lib_sqlite3.c:(.text+0x4148): undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_settype'
lib_sqlite3.c:(.text+0x4167): undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_destroy'
and more but I can't paste all.

Comment: Also using -L. should have included the library path

Comment: @MohammedFawaz You have to compile and link with `-pthread` and link with `-ldl` and possibly some other libraries. See https://www.sqlite.org/howtocompile.html